# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v4.1.1 and when i'm trying to use Link component - i get a warning:

```
Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, 
but its value is `undefined`.
```

and also an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
```

Error is in the Link component on this string:

```
var href = this.context.router.history.createHref(typeof to === 'string' ? { pathname: to } : to);
```

Why router is undefined?

I'm importing BrowserRouter and Route in one of mine component which is responsible only for rendering selected page in the menu. And a Link importing in another component, which is actually a Menu component with unordered list.

I'll attach all my components if needed. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please attach component code. Your menu component should have a parent Route component.

Comment: Oh. Routes and a Header, which contains Menu component - are siblings. Is this only way to solve a problem? This will change structure of mu app.

Comment: Your Menu component should be wrapped by the Router component. This is the only requirement for your Links to work.

Comment: And for history, read this https://github.com/ReactTraining/history. Create a history object and provide that to your Router of choice. Then you can simply import the history object wherever you need it.

Comment: Whether correctly I understand you, that i need to render my Menu everytime i click the Link?  Isn't it is pretty weird to render static component, which is the same at every page?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do... If you can, please put your sample code on pastebin, otherwise we're just playing broken telephone.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonoff here it is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499919/the-context-router-is-marked-as-required-in-link-but-its-value-is-undefine  
sorry, i dont know how to attach links in a right way.

Comment: Exactly what I thought. Your menu should be nested inside the BrowserRouter component. Otherwise it will not have the context of routes to link to. Reason being, you can have multiple Routers in your app, each using a different history object.

Comment: That's not very rational i think. Isn't there any way to render only pages, without Header in react-router?
And hank you for you help!

Comment: You can structure your layout however you want. You just have to have your links inside the Router component, no way to bypass that. Of course you can always manually use an anchor tag with a href to your exact path. In this way you will not have to use the Link component, but that's not the recommended way.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use this

```
var href = this.context.router.history.createHref(typeof to === 'string' ? { pathname: to } : to);
```

You need to register router with your component as following
in your component put this code

```
 static contextTypes = { 
   router: React.PropTypes.object 
}
```