# ReactJS Link in a button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class NavItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Link to={'/test'}>
            <div className="navbar__item">
                <img src={'png/navigation/' + this.props.icon}/>
            </div>
        </Link>
    }
}
```

Where the link will be passed in via a prop. But I'm not sure how to do that as console is telling me that it needs to be wrapped in Router and Route.

How can I get this to work?

---

Console is giving me this:

```
Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

---

I managed to do it like this:

```
render() {
        return <BrowserRouter>
            <Link to={this.props.url}>
                <div className="navbar__item">
                    <img src={'png/navigation/' + this.props.icon}/>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </BrowserRouter>
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for routing that uses a button to redirect, as opposed to a `Link`? `history.push` in an on click handler can accomplish the same thing

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure, this is just meant to be a button that sends the user to another page in my app. Is Link the right way to do it? or should I just use an <a> tag?

Comment: Link is commonly used in react than Anchor tag. I don’t see you receiving link as prop in your code and also where is console log. Please share relevant information

Comment: @HemadriDasari I have updated my question with what's in console.

Comment: The Link should be under Routes which means NavItem should be called under routes

Comment: @HemadriDasari but my routes are all stored in App.js

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499919/the-context-router-is-marked-as-required-in-link-but-its-value-is-undefine

Comment: @HemadriDasari I managed to get it working, please see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just looking to use `history.push` as an onclick handler. It does the same thing as `Link`.

```
handleRouteChange = () => {
  history.push(this.props.routeName)
}

render() {
  return (
    <button onClick={this.handleRouteChange}>
      click
    </button>
  )
}
```

At some point in your app initialization you should be passing in a `history` object. import whatever component that needs `history`. It has a `push` method.

```
export const history = createHashHistory()
<Router history={history}>
  <Routes />
</Router>
```

Comment: Where is history object coming from?

Comment: Updated. It's the same object that you pass into react route's HOC